# How can I call a function in a component from other components in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have the following component structure:

[image]

This is the Input component. When the onChange event is triggered, the validate function is called.

```
import React, {FC, useState} from 'react';

interface InputProps {
    config : {}
}

/**
 * @param config
 * @constructor
 */
const Input: FC<InputProps> = ({config}) => {

    /**
     * @param inputValue
     */
    const validate: Function = (inputValue: any) =>
    {
        // Does input validation 
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <input 
                onChange={(event) => {
                    validate(event.target.value);
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Input;
```

This is my App.tsx. I would like to call validation of all inputs in the button onClick event.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Form from './components/Form/Form';
import Input from './components/UI/Input/Input';
import Button from './components/UI/Button/Button';

const App = () => {

  return(
    <div className="app">
        <Form title="Simple form">
            <Input label="Email address"/>
            <Input label="Password"/>
            <Button config={{
                text: 'Sign in',
                onClick: (event) => {
                    // Here I would like to call the validatе method on the email address and  
                    // password inputs, but I don’t know how to do this yet.
                }
            }}/>
        </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It's a bit anti-pattern in React to do this, but you can use [React.forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref) and the [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) hook to accomplish this.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for the comment. I recently started researching react. If this is an anti-pattern, how should I do it right?

Comment: The more "React" way to do this would be to have `App` or `Form` hold the form state, i.e. the "source of truth" with the button in the same component, pass the state and updater callbacks down to the inputs. See [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the useful information exists in the comments section via experts, here is just an implementation of what you need.

##### Lifting State Up

we need to lift the state from the `Input` component to it's parent component.

in the `App` component:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Form from './components/Form/Form';
import Input from './components/UI/Input/Input';
import Button from './components/UI/Button/Button';

const App = () => {
 const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
 const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  return(
    <div className="app">
      <Form title="Simple form">
        <Input label="Email address" value={email} onAction={setEmail} />
        <Input label="Password" value={password} onAction={setPassword} />
        <Button config={{
           text: 'Sign in',
           onClick: () => {
             validate(emailAddress);
             validate(password);
           }}
        />
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now, in the `Input` component:

```
const Input: FC<InputProps> = ({value, onAction}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        value={value} 
        onChange={(event) => {onAction(event.target.value)}} 
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Input;
```

##### Explanation:

With changes on `input` element,the `onAction` function will invoke.
`onAction` method is a `setState` function which you passed on the `App` component, so every change in the `input` element will update the `email` and `password` variables.

Now, in the `App` component, you have the `password` and `email` values, so validate them easily with your `Button` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lift up the validate function to do the validation on click of button.
Pass reference of the function to the components like input.